# How to find this transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> If $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ and $T(x, y, z) =
>  (x+ 2y−z, x+z,4x−4y+ 5z)$, how do I find the transformation matrix
>   with respect to the standard basis?

So from what I've gathered $T(x,y,z)=A(x,y,z)$ when $A$ is the transformation matrix with respect to the standard basis hence does that make $A=T(x,y,z)(x,y,z)^{-1}$. However I don't believe this is correct hence how do I go about finding this matrix?

Comment: Kindly use MathJax to typeset your questions. As for the question itself : you apply $T$ on each element of the standard basis, that gives you three vectors. These vectors will be the columns of the transformation matrix representing $T$. Attempt this and get back.

Comment: What goes wrong when you just imitate the similar examples in the book?

Comment: It clearly can’t be correct: what’s the inverse of a vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to calculate the images of the standard basis vectors and put the columns into a matrix. We have

\begin{align}
T(e_x) = T(1, 0, 0) &= (1, 1, 4)^\intercal, \\
T(e_y) = T(0, 1, 0) &= (2, 0, -4)^\intercal, \\
T(e_z) = T(0, 0, 1) &= (-1, 1, 5)^\intercal.
\end{align}

Hence, the transformation matrix $A$ is

$$A = \big(T(e_x), T(e_y), T(e_z) \big) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & - 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 4 & -4 & 5 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Hi Jan, that's perfect thanks, if I were to use this method for a different basis say e={(−1,1,2),(−2,1,4),(−1,1,4)} I'd get:

Comment: T(ex)=T(-1,1,2)=(-1,1,2)

Comment: T(ey)=T(-2,1,4)=(-4,2,8)

Comment: T(ez)=T(-1,1,4)=(-3,-3,12)

Comment: Is the transformation matrix wrt the basis e still (T(ex) T(ey) T(ez))

Comment: Yes, but you have a mistake in your calculation. $T(-1, 1, 4) = (-3, 3, 12)$.