# how to find standard basis, by RREF determine a basis for the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Define a linear transformation φ: R3 −→ R3 by putting
x x+2y+3z φ y = 2x+3y+4z .
z x+y+z 3B
(a) Let B be the standard basis for R . Determine the matrix A = MB(φ) of φ with respect to B.

Comment: I have no idea what "x x+2y+3z φ y = 2x+3y+4z . z x+y+z 3B" means!  Could you put it in standard "(x, y, z)--> " form?

Comment: (x,y,z)=(x+2y+3z,2x+3y+4z,x+y+z)

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for mathematical expressions instead of obscure and poorly-supported Unicode characters.

Comment: The columns of $A$ are the images of the standard basis vectors.

Comment: In your title you ask about a kernel, but there’s not one word about that in the body of the question. What exactly are you asking here? The question in the body of your post is effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3586787/265466 and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, better would be f(x,y,z)= (x+ 2y+ 3z 2x+ 3y+ 4z, x+ y+ z) but I understand it.  The kernel is all (x, y, z) such that x+ 2+ 3z= 0, 2x+ 3y+ 4z= 0, and x+ y+ z= 0.  One obvious solution is (0, 0, 0).  The question is what other (x, y, z) satisfy the equations.  From x+ y+ z= 0, z= -x- y.  Putting that into the other equations, x+ 2y+ 3z= x+ 2y+ 3(-x- y)= x+ 2y- 3x- 3y= -2x- y= 0 so y= -2x and then z= -x- y= -x+ 2x= x.  Then 2x+ 3y+ 4z= 2x+ 3(-2x)+ 4(x)= 2x- 6x+ 4x= 6x= 0.  YES! y= -2x and z= x satisfy the equations for any x.  So (x,y,z)= (x, -2x, x)= x(1, -2, 1). So the single vector, (1, -2, 1), is a basis for the kernel.

Comment: Define a linear transformation P: R3 −→ R3 by putting
P(x,y,z)=(x+2y+3z,2x+3y+4z,x+y+z)

(a) Let B be the standard basis for R . Determine the matrix A = MB(P) of P with respect to B. 
(b) Find the reduced row echelon form RREF(A) of A. Hence determine a basis for the kernel Ker(P) of P and for the image Im(P) of P.   The whole QN goes like this so that means in order to get the kernel basis we have to get the RREF first any idea on how to the QN. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Oh, bother.  My previous answer wasn't good enough because it wasn't in the right form?

To find the matrix representing P(x,y,z)= (x+2y+3z,2x+3y+4z,x+y+z) look at what P(1,0,0), P(0,1,0), and P(0,0,1) are.  Multiplying any matrix by $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ gives the first column of the matrix, by $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ gives the second column, and by $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. P(1,0,0)= (1+2(0)+3(0), 2(1)+ 3(0)+ 4(0), 1+ 0+ 0)= (1, 2, 1), P(0,1,0)= (0+2(1)+3(0), 2(0)+ 3(1)+ 4(0), 0+ 1+ 0)= (1, 2, 1), and P(0,0,1)= (0+2(0)+3(1), 2(0)+ 3(0)+ 4(1), 0+ 0+ 1)= (3, 4, 1).

So the matrix representation is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. To row reduce that subtract twice the first row from the second row and subtract the first row from the third row to get $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$.  Since the second column is $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ we can subtract the second row from the third row the divide the second row by -2 to get $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  The kernel is given by (x,y,z) such that x+y+ 3z= 0 and z= 0.  With z= 0, x+ y+ 3z= x+ y= 0, y= -x.  The kernel consists of vectors of the form (x, -x, 0] x(1, -1, 0) so a basis for the kernel is {(1, -1, 0)}.

If we were to multiply the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ by (x,y,x) we would, again, get $(x+ y+ 3z, z, 0)$ which, since x, y, and z can be any values, that is all vectors of the form $(a, b, 0)= (a, 0, 0)+ (0, b, 0)= a(1, 0, 0)+ b(0, 1, 0)$ so that ${(1,0,0),(0,1,0)}$ is a basis for the image.